# GIF Logical Screen Width not equal to PIL.Image.info 's size

Tags: python, binary, hex, python-imaging-library, gif

I'm using WinHex looking at a gif:
[bocchi,gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI3KQ.gif)
but when I load the image using PIL.Image.open(), I find that the size in the image's info is not equal to what I computed.

Here is what WinHex shown:

```
Offset      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F

00000000   47 49 46 38 39 61 68 01  40 01 F5 00 00 12 1D 25   GIF89ah @ ?   %
00000010   22 1E 21 17 23 2C                                  " ! #,
```

Here is how do I compute it's width:  `0x68 + 0x01 * 256 = 353 px`
And here is PIL's output:
[PIL output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKEhB.png)

```bash
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> img = Image.open(fp)
>>> img.size
(360, 320)
```

I want to figure out why this happend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0x68 is hex, so you need:

```
68hex + 256 = 104 + 256 = 360
```